# Loading GIF for iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a iFrame that shows a loading gif as the content loads. The content it loads is simply a PDF download generated by my php script. The problem is that it won't stop showing the loading bar even after the pdf has downloaded.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      function hideLoading() { 
           document.getElementById('divLoading').style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById('divFrameHolder').style.display = "block"; 
       } 
</script> 


<div id="divLoading"> 
    <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" /> 
</div> 
<div id="divFrameHolder" style="display:none"> 
    <iframe src="http://example.com/pdf.php?o=<?php echo $order_number; ?>" onload="hideLoading()" frameborder="0"> 

    </iframe> 
</div>
```

Comment: This should work as expected, do you see the iframe?

Comment: Yes the iFrame shows the loading gif. The problem is that it doesn't go away when the download starts

Comment: What happens here: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ws7ur4qk/ ? When you don't see the pdf, which browser are you using?

Comment: The PDF is not supposed to show in the iframe, instead it is just a download. So I want it to stop showing the gif as soon as the download starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written `hideLoading()`, it expects that function to be inside the iframe, not in the containing window.  If the iframe is in the same domain as the containing document, then you could call the function in the containing document instead with code like this:

```
onload="window.parent.hideLoading();"
```